# Attaching a method to a dynamically created element within Polymer

Tags: polymer

Is it possible to attach dynamically created elements to methods within the element?
For illustration purposes, the method 'alertMe' is not called, and is probably not being attached correctly. Changing the callback from ready to let's say created would not allow me to use the selector "this.$"

```
<polymer-element name="decorated-button">
   <template>
      <div id="container"></div>
   </template>
   <script>
      Polymer('decorated-button', {
           ready: function(){
              var button = document.createElement('button');
              button.setAttribute('on-click','{{alertMe}}');
              this.$.container.appendChild(button);
           },
           alertMe: function(){
               alert("From alert");
            }
      });
   </script>
</polymer-element>
```

I'm looking to be able to create n elements dynamically, and to be able to call a method internally to take action and decide which element n initiated the action. The way I'm approaching it feels like I'm missing an underlying concept...open to any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: We typically use data-binding features for something like this. You can dynamically stamp a bunch of buttons based on a data model and get the index/value of the button that was clicked: http://jsbin.com/coqiqeve/1/edit. Is there something more you want to do?

Comment: That actually will work out. I'm essentially creating additional elements based upon the user's Light DOM...so I guess I can just create models in ready(). Thanks! Didn't see it that way before.